# lsusb finds flash drive, fdisk doesn't

Tags: data-recovery, usb-drive, fdisk, lsusb

I have a Kingston 64gb USB flashdrive that isn't working.
When I use the command lsusb I get the following: '

```
Bus 002 Device 021: ID 0951:1665 Kingston Technology Digital DataTraveler SE9 64GB
```

So it finds my Kingston flasdrive. Searching learned me that I now need to use "sudo fdisk -l". This does not show the Kingston drive. I only get:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x38601c96

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   552536063   276164608    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       552538110  1250263039   348862465    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       552538112  1197832191   322647040    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6      1197834240  1201831935     1998848   82  Linux swap /  Solaris
/dev/sda7      1201833984  1250263039    24214528   83  Linux
```

I also tried using GParted, but this program also cannot find the device.
A laptop using windows can also not find the device.

What can be the problem and what steps can I take to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Kind regards
Bert

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please disconnect the drive, wait a few seconds, connect it again, wait some more seconds and then show us the output of `dmesg | tail -n 40`.

Comment: Rinzwind your statement "Also can happen when the power supply of the USB is faulty", do you know how to get around this issue? I believe this is my problem with my USB device I am trying to recover data from. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know 2 reasons to begin with. 1st one is the most likely one.

1. Kernel not loaded the usb storage module. `lsmod` will show if it is. If not ...

   ```
   sudo modprobe usb_storage
   ```

   to add it.
2. Also can happen when the power supply of the USB is faulty.

---

To investigate more you could do a ...

```
strace -o log fdisk -l
```

and post the results on pastebin (it might be a long log).

Comment: 1. The usb_storage is visible when using lsmod

2. When using 'strace -o log fdisk -l' I get no output
    When using'sudo strace -o log fdisk -l' I get the same output as above using 'sudo fdisk -l'